# Category 7A Ethernet cable backward compatibility with 6A

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable

I need to choose Ethernet cables for my home installation. I can buy U/FTP cat.6A or S/FTP cat.7A at the same price. As I know, category 7A provides more bandwidth, but in order to use the highest available bandwidth I need 7/7A connectors (e.g. GG45, **not** RJ45), which are not very popular.

I found that cat.7/7A cables are backwards compatible with categories 5/5E and 6. But I can't figure out if the 7/7A cables are backwards compatible with category 6A cables. Can one say that a link with cat.7A cable and cat.6A connectors is not worse in case of bandwidth than a link with cat.6A cables and connectors? Are there any disadvantages of using 7/7A compared to 6A? Is it possible that any 6A connector or device is or will not be compatible with category 7A cable?

Comment: I think you are confusing category with class.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1295256/s-ftp-or-u-ftp-when-wiring-a-house-with-cat6a-cabels-for-10gbe/1295287#1295287